# Perl's RegExp syntax

Tags: regex, perl

How would you factorize (or not) the following line ?

```
if ($Hour =~ /^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/) { $result = "$1:$2:$3" }
```

Comment: “Factorize” with regex?  You mean like this? `for ($N = ('o' x shift); $N =~ /^(oo+?)\1+$/; $N =~ s/$1/o/g) { print length($1), " " } print length ($N), "\n";` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't use `\d` unless you want to match all Unicode digit characters (such as 𝟚 or ᠕).  If you want to match zero through nine, you must say `[0-9]`.

Unfortunately, you cannot shorten that to

```
if ($Hour =~ /^([0-9]{2}){3}$/) { $result = "$1:$2:$3" }
```

because you care about all of the matches and that will only save the last one.  Likewise

```
if ($Hour =~ /^([0-9]{6})$/) { $result = "$1:$2:$3" }
```

is out.  You could say

```
($result = $Hour) =~ s/([0-9]{2})(?!$)/$1:/g;
```

but you would be trading clarity for a slightly shorter line.

Comment: in “recent” perls you may use `\p{POSIX_Digit}`, but this is no great win in typing.

Answer (score 3):

Looks pretty good to me as it is.

You can replace each `{2}` with another `\d` if you want.

You could use `$result=join":",$Hour=~/^(\d\d)/g` but it's not as strict - it will match any even-length string of digits at the start of a line.

Comment: It will grab any pairs of digits there are, whether or not they immediately follow the previous pair.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. Matching a time can be taken to various level of strictness.
The above would allow for something like `999999`

Another approach to match a 24-hour clock is to use

```
([01]?[4-9]|[012]?[0-3])
```

for the hour-part and then

```
[0-5][0-9]
```

for minutes.

or (for the fun of it), the hour-part can also be matched using

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])
```

Comment: your hour-part reg exp. looks strange.. how does it match something like 23 ??

Comment: -1: Regex is wrong. As previous comment questions, your first hour-part regex does not match `23`. Worse, it *does* match `1703`, but not `10`, `12`, `06`... The second "for the fun of it" version clearly will not match any hour which doesn't include a `2` and, since it requires 1-2 digits before and 1 digit after the `2`, it will fail to match any one- or two-digit number.

Comment: I have the feeling some |'s went astray

Answer (score 1):

I would use `\z` instead of `$`, unless you really want to allow an optional trailing newline character.  Other than that (and the inconsistent capitalization of variables), it's fine.